# Встретимся через вторник

Tags: грамотная-речь, даты

Правильно я понимаю, что если какое-то мероприятие проходит в определённый день недели (в моём примере по вторникам, как сегодня), то при интервале в две недели правильно сказать *"встретимся через две недели"* или *"встретимся через вторник"?* А при интервале в три — *"через три недели"* или *"через два вторника".*

То есть получается, что при упоминании **периода** (в данном случае исчисляемого *неделями)* время отсчитывается с текущего момента до намеченного дня, а при упоминании **дня недели** считаются *пропущенные такие же дни* в промежутке, поэтому в первом случае значение (через сколько) всегда *на один больше.*

Comment: Был мил, никуда не спешил, провел у меня часа четыре. Возобновляет традицию: собирается бывать через вторник. Год 1987 15 марта [Зоя Масленикова. Жизнь отца Александра Меня (1992)]

Answer (score 1):

Когда говорят "*встретимся через две недели*", имеют в виду, что после того, как пройдёт **вторая** неделя (относительно времени, в которое была сказана эта фраза), назначена встреча. Когда говорят "*встретимся через вторник*" (или любой другой день недели), имеется в виду, когда **пройдёт** вторник на следующей неделе и **наступит** на **после** следующей неделе.

**Обычно** фразу "*встретимся через вторник*" говорят во вторник.

И когда говорят "встретимся через две недели", тоже подразумевается, что вторая неделя сначала закончится, ведь мы, говоря так, не имеем в виду, когда пройдет одна неделя, и начнётся новая.

Comment: То, что "обычно фразу говорят во вторник", не совсем верно. Говорят ее совершенно в любой день, это довольно распространенная практика в среде людей, связанных со сложным расписанием; например, педагогов, транспортников: "в следующий вторник у меня нет занятий, а вот через вторник есть" - это вполне говорится и в четверг, скажем.

Comment: Да, я согласен, но перед этим упоминался "другой" вторник. "*в следующий вторник у меня нет занятий*"

Comment: Как действующий преподаватель, свидетельствую: множество раз слышал и без "другого".

Comment: А я и не настаиваю, что так всегда.